# converting matlab code to python code

Tags: python, matlab

How can I convert matlab code to python code?

```
function b = ismonotone( v, tol )
  if ( nargin < 2 )
    tol = 0;
  end

  b = 0;
  dv = diff(v);
  if ( min(dv) >= -tol ) b = bitor( b, 1 ); end
  if ( max(dv) <= tol ) b = bitor( b, 2 ); end
end
```

I know python but not matlab as much. I wanted to know by this example, how function works or how many return values for a function, etc

Comment: I have not understood the return type and last 2 lines. thus I am stucked. and (nargis<2) means args[2]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the intended use of your function is, but here is a translation of it into Python.

```
def diff(v):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, len(v)):
        result.append(v[i] - v[i-1])
    return result

def ismonotone(v, tol=0):
    b = 0
    dv = diff(v)
    if min(dv) >= -tol:
        b = b | 1
    if max(dv) <= tol:
        b = b | 2
    return b
```

Salient points:

- In Matlab, [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) is a built-in function that computes the difference between adjacent elements of an array. It is straightforward to reimplement (though this may not be the most performant way of doing so).
- Since Matlab has awful support for dealing with variadic functions, you have to futz with [`nargin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) (which is equal to the number of arguments passed to the function) and rubbish like that to get things to work at times. So, the Matlab code is basically saying "if I have less than two arguments, set `tol=0`". In Python, we can just use default values for arguments instead (`tol=0`).
- When you define a function in Matlab, you write:
  `function return_value = function_name(arguments)`
  Whatever the value of the `return_value` variable (in this case, `b`) is whenever control leaves the function (i.e. whenever either the end-of-scope `end` statement or a `return` statement is reached), that is what gets returned. The `return` statement in Matlab does not accept an "argument" in the same way that the Python `return` statement does. Of course, Python, like most reasonable languages, uses explicit return statements.
- [`bitor(a, b)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitor.html) in matlab is equivalent to `a | b` in Python.

Comment: but nargin takes input parameters, should we have to give args?

Comment: @sam I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you're asking why the Matlab code isn't e.g. `nargin(something)`, that's because you can sometimes call Matlab functions without even using parentheses (I don't understand this part of Matlab all that well myself). Notice that on the docs page for `nargin`, there are two options given for syntax: `nargin` and `nargin(fx)`. You would only want to use the latter form if e.g. you were in function `ismonotone` and you wanted to know about the number of arguments to _some other_ function `foo`, in which case you would write `nargin('foo')`.